# border-radius not working by using PIE support?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css3pie

I want to give border-radius 50% for internet explorer 8, I am using PIE library but still it's not working.

I use the following css:

```
.format-circle {
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    display: table;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
    behavior: url(../../PIE/PIE.htc) !important;
    position:relative !important;
}
```

And the following html:

```
<div class="media-left media-middle">
    <div class="format-circle format-practical">
        <div class="format-circle-content">
            <h1>Practical</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have used the `.htaccess` file to enable the `.htc` file support as well.

My application is static web application, and isn't using apache or any other server. Not sure if the `.htaccess` is helpful in this situation or not.

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? How does your file tree look like?

Comment: IAPages/PIE/(all files related to PIE). and my css file path location is IAPages/www-redesign/css folder.

Comment: I've used CSSPie a lot in the past. In fact, I was a big fan of it. However this is 2016. We really should be supporting IE8 users any more. And even if we do have to, we shouldn't be getting hung up about them getting a 100% perfect view of our site. My advice now is just to leave it be. Don't bother with CSSPie at all; just let IE8 users go without rounded corners. It won't make any difference to them using the site.